# Extract text between brakets tags in php using Regex

Tags: php, regex

I have the following content in a string (query from the DB), example:

```
$fulltext = "Thank you so much, {gallery}art-by-stephen{/gallery}. As you know I fell in love with it from the moment I saw it and I couldn’t wait to have it in my home!"
```

So I only want to extract what it is between the `{gallery}` tags, I'm doing the following but it does not work:

```
$regexPatternGallery= '{gallery}([^"]*){/gallery}';
preg_match($regexPatternGallery, $fulltext, $matchesGallery);
if (!empty($matchesGallery[1])) {
    echo ('<p>matchesGallery: '.$matchesGallery[1].'</p>');
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you explain why you have written `[^"]*`? Other thing, instead of testing if the capture group is empty or not, change the quantifier to `+` and write: `if (preg_match(...)) {` *(because in this case when this test succeeds, the capture group exists and is not empty)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$regexPatternGallery= '/\{gallery\}(.*)\{\/gallery\}/';
```

You need to escape / and { with a \ before it. And you where missing start and end / of the pattern.

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fn1

Comment: [**This will fail**](https://regex101.com/r/iY3gA3/1) if there are multiple tags on one line, i.e. `{gallery}by-joe{/gallery} and {gallery}by-tim{/gallery}` will fail

Comment: @Druzion Correct. I didn't see there was that possibillity. Especially since he uses preg_match and not _all

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Andreas answer but differ in `([^"]*?)`

```
$regexPatternGallery= '/\{gallery\}([^"]*?)\{\/gallery\}/';
```

1. Don't forget to put `/` at the beginning and the end of the Regex string. That's a must in PHP, different from other programming languages.
2. `{`,`}`,`/` are characters that can be confused as a Regex logic, so you have to escape it using `\` like `\{`.
3. Use `?` to make the string to non-greedy, thus saves memory. It avoids error when facing this kind of string `"blabla {galery}you should only get this{/gallery} but you also got this instead.{/gallery} Rarely happens but be careful anyway"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegEx:

```
\{gallery\}(.*?)\{\/gallery\}
```

The problem with your RegEx was that you did not escape the `/` in the closing `{gallery}`. You also need to escape `{` and `}`.

You should use `.*?` for a lazy match, otherwise if there are 2 tags in one string, it will combine them. I.e. `{gallery}by-joe{/gallery} and {gallery}by-tim{/gallery}` would end up as:

```
by-joe{/gallery} and {gallery}by-tim
```

However, using a lazy match, you would get 2 results:

```
by-joe
by-tim
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/iL5wE1/1)</kbd>